# Доступ и изменение объекта класса Adorner в WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, .net

Проблема в том, что я не могу спроектировать программу так, чтобы объект в виде коллекции можно было добавить в ComboBox.ItemsSource, если ComboBox находится в декоративном слое Adorner. Получается только с полем static, напрямую обратившись к классу.

Сам Adorner возникает над этим слоем:

```
<local:MyTextBlock Text="{Binding Name, Mode=TwoWay}" IsInEditMode="{Binding Edit, Mode=TwoWay}""/>
```

MyTextBlock - наследник TexBlock. В классе  MyTextBlock есть событие начала редактирования, где создается этот декоративный слой MyAdorner:

```
private MyAdorner _adorner;
private static void IsInEditModeUpdate(DependencyObject obj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
   MyTextBlock myTextBlock = obj as MyTextBlock;
   AdornerLayer layer = AdornerLayer.GetAdornerLayer(MyTextBlock);
   MyTextBlock._adorner = new MyAdorner(myTextBlock);
   layer.Add(MyTextBlock._adorner);
}
```

Конструктор декоративного слоя MyAdorner выглядит так (визуально это будет комбобокс):

```
private readonly ComboBox _comboBox;
public MyAdorner(MyTextBlock adornedElement) : base(adornedElement)
        {
            _collection = new VisualCollection(this);
            _comboBox = new ComboBox();
            Binding binding = new Binding("Text") {Source = adornedElement};
            _comboBox.SetBinding(ComboBox.TextProperty, binding);
            _collection.Add(_comboBox);
         // Тут возникает проблема с dicResult - объектом словаря:
            DicParse dicParse = new DicParse(_comboBox.Text, dicResult);
            _comboBox.ItemsSource = dicParse;
        }
```

**Мне нужно как-то передать этому адорнеру объект словаря dicResult, созданного в основном потоке программы. Я не понимаю где это сделать, как вычленить объект адорнера в основном потоке, к тому же он зависит от MyTextBlock.**

(DicParse - парсер словаря, возвращает коллекцию из пары слов.)

Общий вид данной части XAML если нужно добавлю.

Comment: Простите великодушно, а **зачем** вам `ComboBox` с данными в `Adorner`'е? Он для этого не предназначен.

Какую настоящую задачу вы решаете?

Comment: >Какую настоящую задачу вы решаете?
По щелчку на слове выводятся варианты перевода, один из которых можно выбрать.

Comment: @Maxaz: Вы идёте от внешнего вида, а не от функциональности. Сделайте нормальную архитектуру. На уровне VM список слов превращается в список VM-объектов, представляющих слово и варианты перевода. На уровне отображения такой объект отображается `UserControl`'ом, который при щелчке показывает дополнительный UI. Зачем вам Adorner, ума не приложу.

Comment: @VladD а как реализовать появление дополнительного UI?

Comment: @Maxaz: Ну, по-всякому. Например: onclick -> AdditionalUI.Visibility = Visibility.Visible. Или Click = Command (ShowTranslations), в команде VM.IsTranslationVisible = true, в UI `AdditionalUI Visible={Binding IsTranslationVisible, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}`. Или ещё тысячей разных способов.